# Code conversion swift 2 --> 3 resulting in binary operator error at index path

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, swift2, indexpath

Was using Xcode 7 with swift 2. 
App worked fine.
Updated to Xcode 8. It automatically converted code from swift 2 --> swift 3.
Now I have a problem with code for my Table view.

Error is with this line of code:

```
if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 || indexPath == 1 {
        counter = 0
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Day1", sender: self)
}
```

As it says that binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands type 'index path' and 'int'

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 || indexPath == 1 {
        counter = 0
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Day1", sender: self)
    }

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 1 {
        counter = 1
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Day2", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexPath == 1` doesn't even work in Swift 2. And is it intended that if the row is `1` than both segues are going to be performed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error comes from this piece of code

```
indexPath == 1
```

you need to get it's `row` property which is of type `Int`

```
indexPath.row == 1
```

---

Also note that there is no need to convert `IndexPath` to `NSIndexPath`

```
indexPath.row
```

then I think you probably don't want to check second condition in first if statement because in this case second if statement won't be executed how you want to

```
if indexPath.row == 0
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        counter = 0
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Day1", sender: self)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        counter = 1
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Day2", sender: self)
    }
}
```